# Dynamics Crm - Get Triggering lookup field on quick create form load in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

Does anyone know if its possible to get the lookup field that a quick create form was launched from in javascript.

I know I can get the triggering entity from the below function but want to know if I can also get the field that was used.

Xrm.Page.context.getQueryStringParameters()

The context is that I have an entity which has multiple lookups to contact, I want to dynamically set a contact type and display different fields in the quick create form based on the contact type. I know I could add a contact type for the user to select but don't want to go down that road.

I have a feeling what I want to do is not possible but thought I would put it out there and see if anyone has a solution.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use OOB relationship mappings to copy data from parent entity to child entity.